# Setting CSRFtoken in session

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting value of the csrf token set by server on my jsp and I want to set the same value in session and pass it to server without sending through request parameter.

So, I tried `session.setAttribute`, but it is not working.

```
<input type="hidden" name="8f16a344767af48bd99493a8c7f1f6a0" 
value="<c:out value='${fn:escapeXml(csrfPreventionSalt)}'/>"/>
<%session.setAttribute("csrftoken","8f16a344767af48bd99493a8c7f1f6a0");%>
```

I am getting `8f16a344767af48bd99493a8c7f1f6a0` as value of csrftoken. Where value is some random number.

Comment: you need to pass it via a form using the name parameter <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="...

Comment: If you use spring check https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: Actually I checked this link.I am using jqgrid on jsp so I am not having form action on it.

Comment: How do you post your data to the server ?

Comment: ajax call on grid

Comment: I suppose your are using an ajax post request. just append you csrf token to your ajax request using the data parameter (cf. jQuery documentation)

Comment: I will try to check it. thanks